# How do I display a list of countries in a list activity?

Tags: java, android

I am making a trivia app about Europe. I want to use a list activity to display a list of all 50 countries. I have a array in strings.xml with all 50 countries. How should I do this? Do list activities have their own layouts like list fragments?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html, try yourself first, tell us what problems you are having with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add array in your adapter. For example:

```
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);   
        listItem = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country);  
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItem);  
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you want to make a more custom UI for list, then please have a look [at my write up here](http://androidkeeda.com/android-delete-multi-select-items-listview).

Comment: Hi Moin. Just so you're aware, you *must* disclose your affiliation with sites if you include them in your post. For more information, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)